# java - How to iterate or go over an object structure? e.g. to sanitize all strings

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, sanitization

Due to a legacy code I need to implement a way to sanitize (remove special characters or dangerous HTML) all Strings contained in all objects that we're getting in our Spring controllers.
I wrote my own implementation HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, so I can intercept any parameter and sanitize the object before is sent to the controller.
Also, I wrote an utility class that sanitizes the most common java "types": beans (using jsr-303 and reflection), arrays, collections, maps and, of course, single strings.

```
public class ObjectSanitizer {
public static Object sanitizeObject(Object object)
            throws EsapiValidationException {
        Object result = getDefaultResult(object);
        if (object instanceof String)
            result = santitizeString((String) object);
        else {
            if (object != null) {
                if (object instanceof Collection<?>) {
                    result = sanitizeCollection((Collection<?>) object);
                } else if (object instanceof Map<?,?>) {
                    result = santizeMap(object);
                }  else if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
                    result = santizeArray(object);
                } else {
                    result = sanitizeObjectWithJSR(object);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }  ...  Concrete sanitizers  ...  }
```

My question is: is there a correct way (built-in functionality, API, design pattern) to do this?
Thanks in advance to you all java gurus and beginners like me.

Comment: What do you mean by sanitising a String?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 we want to remove dangerous HTML tags and special characters from all input strings, this in server-side

Answer (score 1):

Can you just sanitize the text output before it's written to the response, instead of trying to sanitize String objects in Javaland?

I think this is a good example of what you could do using Java Filters (not a Spring specific feature). Obviously don't home roll the text sanitizing yourself, there should be plenty of libraries out there that can do it for you.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/anti-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter.html

Comment: Hi @Jazzepi, thanks! I also tried to use a filter, but I'm getting problems when it comes to JSON objects inside the request body.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're getting problems when you tried to use a filter? Are you munging your data in a bad way? Are you unable to manipulate the request body successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Without having a restricted set of Object types this is impossible to sanitize in all cases. Assuming the set of Object types is limited (e.g. String, Map, Collection) then it should be possible by having sanitize methods for each type. You won't really be able to do much other than provide a consistent interface (e.g. `ISanitizable` which has a `sanitize()` method) and then recursively call that depending on the type of Object (given the Map could have more Maps and more Collections...). It is also worth bearing in mind that modifying the objects may have undesirable effects (e.g. if you are creating a new object to replace the existing one), so careful testing will be needed to make sure you aren't inadvertently breaking other parts of the codebase.

Comment: Thanks @Dororo! I'll bear it in mind, in fact, I think that the test package of my API will be much larger than my main classes.